# What are messages in Android Services?

Tags: android

Studying http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingService  ,

in the code, I see this

```
Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
```

But not much has been said about this. I tried running the code and started the service using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewCheckpointService.class);
startService(intent);
```

The service starts correctly, however I face a null pointer when it comes obtaining the message. That is to say that the variable msg is null.

Could anyone explain what the Message object is used for, and how I can use it? (best with examples).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here study the android handler method() [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Messages and Handlers are a way of communicating with other parts of your program in a thread-safe manner. It's sort of like Intents in that it can carry a bundle of information, but it's essentially an Android-approved way to tell one part of your program that something has occurred somewhere else.

API documentation link for posterity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html